# Problem with scanning and printing strings in C

Tags: arrays, c, printf, scanf

I am trying to read a file with the same pattern of data in each line of file. The numbers are printed correctly but the string of characters is printed incorrectly - it prints the first letter more times than it should (both strings). I am actually new to programming and arrays are hard for me to understand. Thanks for any help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void )
{
int  kamera[1000], den[1000], hodina[1000], minuta[1000];
char registracka[1000], mesic[1000];
int i = 0;

while(!feof(stdin))
{
    scanf("%d: %s %s %d %d: %d", &kamera[i], &registracka[i], &mesic[i], &den[i], &hodina[i], &minuta[i]);
    i=i+1;
}
i = 0;
printf("%d: %s %s %d %d:%d\n",kamera[i], &registracka[i], &mesic[i], den[i], hodina[i], minuta[i]);
printf("%d: %s %s %d %d:%d\n",kamera[i+1], &registracka[i+1], &mesic[i+1], den[i+1], hodina[i+1], minuta[i+1]);
printf("%d: %s %s %d %d:%d\n",kamera[i+2], &registracka[i+2], &mesic[i+2], den[i+2], hodina[i+2], minuta[i+2]);
printf("%d: %s %s %d %d:%d\n",kamera[i+3], &registracka[i+3], &mesic[i+3], den[i+3], hodina[i+3], minuta[i+3]);
printf("%d: %s %s %d %d:%d\n",kamera[i+4], &registracka[i+4], &mesic[i+4], den[i+4], hodina[i+4], minuta[i+4]);
printf("%d: %s %s %d %d:%d\n",kamera[i+5], &registracka[i+5], &mesic[i+5], den[i+5], hodina[i+5], minuta[i+5]);
printf("%d: %s %s %d %d:%d\n",kamera[i+6], &registracka[i+6], &mesic[i+6], den[i+6], hodina[i+6], minuta[i+6]);
return 0;
}
```

My input:

```
10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30
10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30
10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30
10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30
10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30
10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30
```

The output i want:

```
10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30
10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30
10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30
10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30
10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30
10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30
```

The output i get:

```
10: AAAAAAABC-12-34 OOOOOOOct 1 7:30
10: AAAAAABC-12-34 OOOOOOct 1 7:30
10: AAAAABC-12-34 OOOOOct 1 7:30
10: AAAABC-12-34 OOOOct 1 7:30
10: AAABC-12-34 OOOct 1 7:30
10: AABC-12-34 OOct 1 7:30
10: ABC-12-34 Oct 1 7:30
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: We need to see what you 've tried

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct:

```
scanf("%d: %s %s %d %d: %d", &kamera[i], &registracka[i], &mesic[i]...
```

`mesic` and `registracka` are arrays of characters, not arrays of strings.  Each time you read a string from input, the chars from that string get copied into the char buffer at offset i.

Better.  Declare mesic and registracka as arrays of char pointers.

```
char* registracka[1000] = {0};  // replace 1000 with the maximum number of lines you expect
char* mesic[1000] = {0};
```

Then allocate a sufficiently large enough buffer for each string you want to scanf characters into.

```
while(!feof(stdin))
{
    registracka[i] = malloc(BIG_ENOUGH+1);
    mesic[i] = malloc(BIG_ENOUGH+1);

    scanf("%d: %s %s %d %d: %d", &kamera[i], registracka[i], mesic[i], &den[i], &hodina[i], &minuta[i]);
    i=i+1;
}
```

Where `BIG_ENOUGH` is the longest string you expect to read.

Notice the adjustment to the `scanf` parameters as well (dropped the ampersand for and registracka and mesic)

Your printf statement needs similar treatment:

```
printf("%d: %s %s %d %d:%d\n",kamera[i+1], registracka[i+1], mesic[i+1], den[i+1], hodina[i+1], minuta[i+1]);
```

Don't forget to free the strings too after you are done printing

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
     free(registracka[j]); 
     registracka[j]=NULL;

     free(mesic[j]);
     mesic[j] = NULL:
}
```